# Selenium Webdrive find visible element

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

So i have this form for anti-spam. Because of that it creates for each input about 9 or so inputs. This inputs have and id of 'NameInput' + X where x is a number generated (from 1 to 9 -- depending on the number of inputs). I'm using php and I want to select the one input that is visible. I would use the id but each time the page is loaded, because of the random number each time the input's id visible is different.
I've googled it and try to find a code that selects the id (first part of it that is the same for all inputs) and the display style. Tried a lot of code snippets but no success. This is where I am now but i got this error.

> An invalid or illegal selector

```
$this->_webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('[id^=NameInput]:not[style=display:none]'))
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I ended up with:

```
$nameInputs = $this->_webDriver->findElements(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('input[id^="NameInput"]'));
    foreach ($nameInputs as $name) {
        if($name->getCSSValue('display') === 'block') {
            $name->sendKeys('Jellos');
```

It might help someone!